# libcurl c++ curl_easy_init terminates without any exception

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows-7, libcurl

I am trying to make a HTTP request using **libcurl**.

I am using **Windows 7** (64-bit) + **eclipse MARS** (64-bit ) + **curl 7.40.0** . I configured the Include (-I) and Library (-L) for Compiler and Linker.

Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main() {
    CURL *curl;
    std::cout << "Before";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    std::cout << "After";
    return 0;
}
```

I am able to get this code working in Code Blocks.

However, the program crashes in Eclipse. It terminates without giving any error.

Comment: Try to initialize the winsock stuff first `int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  curl = curl_easy_init(); 
// .. }`

Comment: @FirstStep - I reduced the code for simplicity. However, adding `curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);` doesn't resolve it. It seems more like, in 64-bit version, the linker cannot resolve it and in 32-bit, it terminates due to some error which is not published.

Comment: Edited the question as i am now able to get it working in CodeBlocks. Problem remains same with Eclipse.